# Can Queryql-playground be installed in Gatsby globally?

Tags: gatsby

I would like to replace the default Gatsby Queryql feature with the newer QueryQL-playground. Can the change be made globally or does it have to be done on a per project basis?

I have installed it on a particular project but would like to do it globally, in order to save time.